How to detect the fingerprint (locate it, no need to recognize it) from photo (contain fingerprint and other objects)?
I need to detect fingerprint (locate it, no need to recognize it) from photo (contain fingerprint and other objects). The methods I found are all about extracting features and comparing with database. However, I only want to find the bounding box of fingerprint in a natural photo.
Any suggestions?
I have no idea how to locate it.

Please share more info on the tools you are using/want to use, such as programming languages, libraries, etc. Also share if you have already tried any approaches
